# 500 server error when submitting email with SendGrid + NextJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, sendgrid

I'm trying to follow this tutorial to put an email capture form in a NextJS site: https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-create-a-working-contact-form-in-next-js-459d1fc992ea

Because it's not a full contact form, I dropped all of the fields except the email.

My api/contact.js looks like this:

```
const mail = require('@sendgrid/mail');

mail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);

export default async (req, res) => {
  const body = JSON.parse(req.body);

  const message = `
    Email: ${body.email}
  `;

  const data = {
    to: 'SENDER-EMAIL',
    from: 'RECEIVER-EMAIL',
    subject: `New message from ${body.email}`,
    text: message,
    html: message.replace(/\r\n/g, '<br />'),
  };

  await mail.send(data);

  res.status(200).json({ status: 'OK' });
};
```

And inside index.js, the form looks like this:

```
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className={styles.form}>
          <label htmlFor="email">Email:</label>
          <input
            id="email"
            type="email"
            onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)}
          />
          <button type="submit">Send</button>
        </form>
```

The form displays properly on the site, but I get a 500 error when I try submit an email in production. I also tried on localhost and got an error.

I npm installed the sendgrid package. I also have my secret in a .env.local.

I'm not sure what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are getting an error when you call on `await mail.send(data)`. There could be a couple of reasons for this, but first we should see how to find out what the error is.

We need to wrap the call to send the email in a `try/catch` block. That way we can handle the error and inspect it to see what is wrong. We can also control the response to your front-end instead of dealing with the default 500 handler.

At the bottom of your `api/contact.js` function update to:

```js
try {
  await mail.send(data);
  res.status(200).json({ status: 'OK' });
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
  if (error.response) {
    console.log(error.response.body);
  }
  res.status(400).json({ status: "ERROR", message: error.message });
}
```

Now when there is an error we log the error to the server logs and return a message to the front-end. Note, that message may not be suitable for users and you might want to detect errors and return a better message yourself.

Now you are logging the error you should be able to see what it says. And it should direct you to what I think is one of these issues:

- Your API key is wrong

  Either, you have set it incorrectly, or you added it to your `.env.local` correctly and need to fully restart your server
- Your API key doesn't have permission to send emails

  When you create an API key, you can choose to give it all permissions or just a subset. Make sure your API key has the permission to send emails.
- Your trying to send from an email address that SendGrid doesn't know you own

  To send emails from an email address using SendGrid, you either need to [verify the email address is yours](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/sending-email/sender-verification) or [authenticate that the domain is yours](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/account-and-settings/how-to-set-up-domain-authentication) (domain authentication is recommended for production applications)